# Get callback values from an external script

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I do have an HTML page like the below. When the user clicks on the button, **createToken()** function (available in the script) would be called. Next, the callback function from the script tag would be called where I would be receiving my token in the **setCallbackValues()**. I was trying to migrate this section of code to typescript. I tried using *Promises* and *callbacks* for this purpose (calling the external script dynamically) which in turn gives me an undefined response. Could someone please help me understand how this could be done using typescript.

```
<script type="text/javascript" callBackFunc="setCallbackValues" src="https://www.brusherMat.com/gettoken.do?code=123456"></script>

<input type="button" id="button" onclick="getToken();" value="Send information" />

<form id="submit" method="POST" action="https://www.brusherMat.com/submitAction.do">
...
     <input type="hidden" id="Token" name="Token" />
</form>

getToken() {
  brusherMat.createToken(); // brusherMat is a global variable available in the above script
}

setCallbackValues(token) {
  console.log(token);
  document.getElementById('Token').value = token;
  document.getElementById('submit').submit();
}
```

Comment: Typescript is downward compatible, so if this code is working, it should be totally fine leaving this untouched

Comment: this code works in TypeScript too. Promises and callbacks are part of JS